# [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError);

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entity classes: Country and State, which have the following relationship. Even though I have marked the Country as lazy in the State entity, it's still trying to fetch it, and I am getting an infinite JSON response of country and state, causing an infinite recursion (StackOverflowError). I know I can solve this by using @JsonIgnore on top of State in the Country class. But why is the state getting fetched even after it's marked as (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)?

```java
package com.bezkoder.springjwt.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //@JsonIgnore
    private List<State> states;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<State> getStates() {
        return states;
    }

    public void setStates(List<State> states) {
        this.states = states;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

State.java

```
package com.bezkoder.springjwt.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class State {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Country country;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "state", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<City> cities;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public List<City> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setCities(List<City> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        return id != null && id.equals(((State) obj).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 2021;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "State{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Exception

```
Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_1_, country0_.name as name2_1_ from country country0_
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_10_0_, states0_.id as id1_10_0_, states0_.id as id1_10_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_10_1_, states0_.name as name2_10_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at open/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 873
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at open/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 873
2024-03-16 17:54:22.052  WARN 31312 --- [nio-8771-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.State["country"]->com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Country["states"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]-
```

Comment: The [documentation for ManyToOne.fetch](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html#fetch--) says “The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime.”  It is a hint, not a mandate.

Answer (score 0):

When you send your response, jakson will try to retrieve the attributes, including those with FetchType set to 'LAZY'. I assume you're using spring boot, in which case you probably have the open-in-view option set to 'True' (default value) so there is a risk of problem N+1.

To solve this, you can create response objects (DTO), or use the annotations
[JsonManagedReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html) on `Country.states` and [JsonBackReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html) on `State.country`.

Comment: What's the differnce between JsonManagedReference jsonignore?

Comment: With JsonManagedReference, for each Coutry you will keep Country.states (and each states will not have Country).  It resolved your problem but i think it create a N+1 problem.